# What is a good NetworkStream.Read Buffer Size?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm going to use TcpClient for communication with a system which is connected directly (via cross-cable) to my target system.

The messages I am going to receive are often very simple, in fact they will mostly be XML messages with no more than 10 lines.

Occasionaly, a larger one may go through.

What is a good rule of thumb for defining the buffer size for NetworkStream's (Begin)Read method? In a lot of examples it's 1024 bytes. Does it make any sense to make it very large or very small or is this a good default?

Comment: There is no one rule fit all in this case. You have to do testing by yourself and see what is the best buffer size for you.

Comment: very small is often not a good choice. too much overhead data. if your connection speed is stable & fast enough, try a bigger value.

Comment: Whatever you do, remember that calls to `Read` won't be in 1-1 correspondence with calls to `Write` at the other end - you will need to handle reassembling messages from several calls to `Read`.

Comment: Okay, since the systems will be very close together, not just physically but also topologically (does that make sense?), I will try it with 8192 and work from there. Thanks!  @Damien_The_Unbeliever we will be using delimiters to paste the messages back together.